# Aggregating column values of dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which involves Vendor, Product, Price of various listings on a market among other column values.

[image: Dataframe]

I need a dataframe which has the unique vendors, number of products, sum of their product listings, average price/product and (average * no. of sales) as different columns.

Something like this -

[image: Result]

What's the best way to make this new dataframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using pandas [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). Here is an example based on your data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

>>> f = pd.pivot_table(d, index=['Vendor', 'Sales'], values=['Price', 'Product'], aggfunc={'Price': np.sum, 'Product':np.ma.count}).reset_index()

>>> f['Avg Price/Product'] = f['Price']/f['Product']

>>> f['H Factor'] = f['Sales']*f['Avg Price/Product']

>>> f.drop('Sales', axis=1)

  Vendor  Price  Product  Avg Price/Product  H Factor
0      A    121        4              30.25    6050.0
1      B     12        1              12.00    1440.0
2      C     47        2              23.50     587.5
3      H     45        1              45.00    9000.0
```

Comment: Can you please explain np.ma.count @Rahul? Any ideas how I can get the column for H Factor?

Comment: @harry04 what is the formula for H factor?

Comment: HF = Avg price/product * Number of Sales (for a vendor) from above table.

Comment: @harry04 Updated the answer, values of HF differ from the ones you provided in question, hope I've got it right.

Comment: I don't think 'Sales' should be np.sum @Rahul. It's a constant for each vendor from the original dataframe.

Comment: @harry04, Updated the answer to suit the needs. Please accept if it helped.

Comment: Thanks mate! :) @Rahul

Answer (score 2):

First multiple columns `Number of Sales` with `Price`, then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by dictionary of columns names with aggregate functions, then flatten MultiIndex in columns by `map` and `rename`. :

```
df['Number of Sales'] *=  df['Price']

d1 = {'Product':'size', 'Price':['sum', 'mean'], 'Number of Sales':'mean'}
df = df.groupby('Vendor').agg(d1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
d = {'Product_size':'No. of Product',
     'Price_sum':'Sum of Prices',
     'Price_mean':'Mean of Prices',
     'Number of Sales_mean':'H Factor'
     }
df = df.rename(columns=d).reset_index()
print (df)
  Vendor  No. of Product  Sum of Prices  Mean of Prices  H Factor
0      A               4            121           30.25    6050.0
1      B               1             12           12.00    1440.0
2      C               2             47           23.50     587.5
3      H               1             45           45.00    9000.0
```

Comment: H Factor = Mean of Prices * No. of sales (original dataframe). How can I do that?

Comment: @harry04 - It is `df['H Factor'] *= df['Mean of Prices']`

Comment: your calculation and result for H Factor is different from mine (see my results table above)...

Comment: @harry04 - There is problem last value of last row is `200`, not 55, then get expected output.

Comment: @harry04 - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using groupby(), like this:

```
df.groupby('Vendor').agg({'Products': 'count', 'Price': ['sum', 'mean']})
```

That's just three columns, but you can work out the rest.